# SSRS 2012 fill expression using nested iif Statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on color code issues in a column. I am using a nested if statements. Both portions work by themselves but when tried with nested the portion working from the lookup doesn't work. Below is the my expression.

> > if
> >     (
> >     Lookup(Fields!Equipment_Key.Value,Fields!Equipment_Key.Value,Fields!EW_last_SM.Value, "SM_Info")>
> >     Dateadd("d",+2, lookup(Fields!Equipment_Key.Value,Fields!Equipment_Key.Value,Fields!EICT_Last_SM.Value, "SM_Info")), "RED", 
> >     iif(Me.value = "NOW","YELLOW",
> >     "WHITE")
> >     )<<

Answer (score 0):

The issue was multiple data types in the same column. Workaround was to ad 2 columns and put each part of the if statement in its own column then referenced the 2 columns for the color coding.